# @font-face stopped working

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, blogger

Not sure why but @font-face has stopped working on a number of my sites (Blogger & Wordpress). I previously used Google Drive to host the fonts as below:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Biloxi';
src: url('https://googledrive.com/host/0Bybz--lLp5SvZmc0SGRGOVB4dEE/Biloxi Script-webfont.eot');
src: url('https://googledrive.com/host/0Bybz--lLp5SvZmc0SGRGOVB4dEE/Biloxi Script-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('https://googledrive.com/host/0Bybz--lLp5SvZmc0SGRGOVB4dEE/Biloxi Script-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
 url('https://googledrive.com/host/0Bybz--lLp5SvZmc0SGRGOVB4dEE/Biloxi Script-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('https://googledrive.com/host/0Bybz--lLp5SvZmc0SGRGOVB4dEE/Biloxi Script-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

When it stopped working, I tried hosting the fonts on my server and linking to the fonts in a file as below but even this didn't load the fonts which I found strange.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Shorelines Script';
src: url('ShorelinesScriptBold.eot');
src: url('ShorelinesScriptBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('ShorelinesScriptBold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('ShorelinesScriptBold.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

It seems sporadic so the font will load one minute, but then you refresh and it won't load (e.g. http://hummingbirdgattodesign.blogspot.co.uk/). The problem has been on Blogger and Wordpress and seems to be on Chrome and Firefox.

As a relatively inexperienced coder any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: step 1: remove all these font formats that are no longer supported. Use `woff`/`woff2` for modern browsers, and `eot` *only* if you need IE8 or earlier support (which you shouldn't, given that Microsoft finally dropped IE8 and below almost a year ago). Everything else is either a dead format (like `.svg`) or redudant (like `ttf`/`otf`, which are wrapped by woff byte-for-byte already, and there are no browsers that properly support ttf/otf but not woff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the browser is blocking the request for the web font files because they aren't being sent with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set. Have a look at the Console in the developer tools in Chrome/Firefox and you will see the errors:

> Font from origin 'https://googledrive.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://hummingbirdgattodesign.blogspot.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.

I'd suggest you look for an alternative place to host the font files, as I don't think Google Drive will set this header for you (eg: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin error on Google Drive web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364662/access-control-allow-origin-error-on-google-drive-web-site)). You'd have more control over this kind of thing by serving from [Amazon AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533888/s3-access-control-allow-origin-header), or the [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) platform.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, however I've already tried hosting the fonts on my domain (e.g the title font here: http://halfmoongatto.blogspot.co.uk/) and it seems to be pulling the same error message. Is there any way around this?

Comment: It looks like the same thing is happening there. Do you have control over your web server? If so you can configure it to send the appropriate header: http://enable-cors.org/server.html